# Encerrar um processo em C# com WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, processo

Tenho uma solução que possui dois projetos. um projeto principal e outro que serve como Updater.

Para realizar a atualização, dentro do projeto principal, chamo um console application da seguinte forma.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Lê arquivo xml e manipula arquivo xml
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.meusite.org.br/Cantina/arquivoXML.xml");
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
        XmlNode node1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/ZipFile");
        string version = node.InnerText;
        string zipfile = node1.InnerText;
        string End = (@"\\aps-serverweb\wwwroot\meusite.org.br\Cantina\");
        string file = (End + zipfile);
        string versionAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        //valida version (versão disponível no servidor para atualização) e versionAssembly (versão do sistema isntalado) 
        if (Convert.ToDouble(version) <= Convert.ToDouble(versionAssembly))
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Sistema Atualizado" + version); 
        }
        else
        {
            //chama o projeto de atualiação de sistema console application IASD.ASCS.Updater
            Process myProc = Process.Start("Updater.exe");

        }
}
```

Ao chamar o processo Updater (console application) o seguinte código e executado.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Xml;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Updater
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nomeExecutavel = "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe";
        foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeExecutavel))
        {
            if (!pr.HasExited) pr.Kill();
        }

        //Lê e manipula arquivo xml com as informações do arquivo zip contendo a atualização disponível
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.meusite.org.br/Cantina/arquivoXML.xml");
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/Version");
        XmlNode node1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Application/ZipFile");
        string version = node.InnerText;
        string zipfile = node1.InnerText;
        string End = (@"\\aps-serverweb\wwwroot\meusite.org.br\Cantina\");
        string file = (End + zipfile);
        string versionAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        //Utiliza os métodos da biblioteca dotnetzip chamada Ionic.zip para baixar e extrair arquivos zip
        ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(file);
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
            {
                zipEntry.Extract(@"C:\IASD\CantinaEscolar\Temp\", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        }

        foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeExecutavel))
        {
            if (!pr.HasExited) pr.Kill();
        }

        //Transfere os arquivos baixados no diretório Temp para o diretório instalação em c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar 
        string dirTemp = @"c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar\Temp";
        string dirInstalacao = @"c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar";
        string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(dirTemp);
        foreach (string item in arquivos)
        {
            string nomedoarquivo = Path.GetFileName(item);
            string destino = Path.Combine(dirInstalacao, nomedoarquivo);
            File.Copy(item, destino, true);
        }
        string[] arquivosApagar = Directory.GetFiles(dirTemp);
        foreach (string item in arquivosApagar)
        {
            File.Delete(item);
        }

        foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeExecutavel))
        {
            if (!pr.HasExited) pr.Start();
        }

        //Encerra o processo Updater
        string nomeExecutavel2 = "Updater.exe";
        foreach (Process pr2 in Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeExecutavel2))
           {
            if (!pr2.HasExited) pr2.Kill();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

O updater basicamente faz o seguinte

1. Encerra o processo principal
2. Verifica se tem uma atualização disponível no diretório através de um arquivo xml. (isso é feito também no processo principal para entrar no Updater).
3. Descompacta para uma pasta temporária.
4. Copia para a pasta de instalação do projeto principal.
5. Exclui os arquivos do diretório `c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar\Temp`

Isso funciona perfeitamente rodando dentro do visual studio.

Agora ao instalar a aplicação em um computador, no momento de copiar os arquivos 'de atualização', provenientes da pasta Temp, para o diretório de instalação, é retornado um erro informando que o arquivo está em execução.

O processo necessário para ser encerrado quando estou rodando a aplicação no Visual Studio chama-se `IASD.ASCS.WPF.vshost`. Já quando a aplicação está instalada, o processo muda de nome, tornando-se `IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe` que é o nome do projeto dentro da solution bem como o nome de seu executável que encontra-se na pasta `bin\Debug`.

Tentei encerrar esse processo das seguintes formas e não obtive sucesso:

```
String nome = "IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe";
        // Obtém lista de processos
        Process[] processos = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process p in processos)
        {
            if (p.ProcessName.ToUpper() == nome.ToUpper())
            {
                // Tenta fechar a janela principal,
                // se falhar invoca o método Kill()
                if (!p.CloseMainWindow())
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }
                p.Close(); // Libera recursos associados.
            }
        }


        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Login.exe");

        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

        Process[] processes1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("Login");

        foreach (Process process1 in processes1)
        {
            process1.Kill();
        }

        Process[] processes2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe");

        foreach (Process process2 in processes2)
        {
            process2.Kill();
        }

        Process[] processes3 = Process.GetProcessesByName("IASD.ASCS.WPF");

        foreach (Process process3 in processes3)
        {
            process3.Kill();
        }

        Process[] processes4 = Process.GetProcessesByName("vshost32");

        foreach (Process process4 in processes4)
        {
            process4.Kill();
        }

        Process[] processes5 = Process.GetProcessesByName("vshost32.exe");

        foreach (Process process5 in processes5)
        {
            process5.Kill();
        }
```

Nenhuma delas funciona quando a aplicação está instalada.

Obs.: O processo Login citado no código é o nome do WPF criado conforme imagem do gerenciador de tarefas do Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia encerrar o processo IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe para que o console application copie os arquivos da pasta temp para a pasta de instalação da aplicação e depois reinicie esse processo?

Answer (score 4):

Não tem como dentro do programa principal, ele mesmo se fechar, antes de chamar o Updater?

```
// verifica se existe uma atualização
// e se existir, inicia o Updater.exe e depois se fecha
if (existeUmaAtualizacao)
{
    Process myProc = Process.Start("Updater.exe");
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Dentro do Updater, talvez seja necessário tentar deletar o arquivo do executável original, dentro de um loop, até conseguir, com um timeout obviamente, senão o Updater pode travar:

```
var timeout = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
while (DateTime.Now < timeout)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete("IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe");
        break;
    }
    catch { }
}

if (!File.Exists("IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe"))
{
    // arquivo foi excluido com sucesso,
    // agora podemos copiar o arquivo atualizado que está na pasta TEMP
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Inclui                                    string wpfExe = @"c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar\IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe";
            File.Delete(wpfExe); Dentro do Updater antes da linha que faz a copia dos arquivos e mesmo assim aparece a mensagem de que o arquivos IASD.ASCS.WPF.exe está sendo executador por outro processo. No debug o erro retorna na linha 56, bem no foreach: foreach (string item in arquivos)        {       string nomedoarquivo = Path.GetFileName(item);
            string destino = Path.Combine(dirInstalacao, nomedoarquivo);
            File.Copy(item, destino, true);
        }

Comment: Ao fazer isso, talvez a aplicação esteja demorando um pouco para se fechar... então dentro do Updater, talvez seja necessário tentar varias vezes obter o acesso ao arquivo, até que ele seja liberado.

Answer (score 1):

**ATENÇÃO:** Embora já tenha usado/testado todas estas técnicas, nunca construí nenhuma aplicação como vou aqui descrever.

O executável `IASD.ASCS.WPF.vshost.exe` é o [Visual Studio hosting process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/hosting-process-vshost-exe?view=vs-2015) para esse projeto. A função deste executável é agilizar o processo de depuração das aplicações evitando a necessidade de criar um novo processo cada vez que se corre a aplicação.

Não tenho a certeza, mas presumo que, a cada execução em que os executáveis tenham sido modificados, é criado um novo [application domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains) para carregar os executáveis e corrê-los. Para que os executáveis possam ser modificados mesmo com o programa a correr, presumo que o *application domain* seja [criado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createdomain?view=net-6.0) com *[shadow copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223064748/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/09/69919.aspx)* - o mesmo processo que o ASP.NET utiliza.

Se em vez de um *updater* tiveres um controlador que lança a tua aplicação num *application domain* separado com *shadow copy* podes controlar a execução da aplicação e atualização. Em caso de ter sido efetuada uma atualização, o *application domain* atual é finalizado e é criado um novo com tempo de paragem mínimo. Se houver o requisito de manter a aplicação em excução, pode ser usado o mesmo mecanismo para lançar de novo a aplicação sempre que o *application domain* seja terminado inesperadamente.